# Does Windows 7 IE 11 support video streaming without plugins

Tags: javascript, windows-7, video-streaming, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I have a very specific target audience that I need to stream live video to (not prerecorded), that must run stock Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7. This means without Flash, Silverlight or any other plugins. Is this possible? My fears are that it is not, but I thought I would ask just in case I'm missing some special feature.

To reiterate:

1 Only needs to support 1 browser, IE 11 running under Window 7

2 No browser plugins

3 JavaScript is ok

Please note that I already tried [broadway](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway), it was not performant enough.

Comment: IE11, is HTML5.. So it should be able to do HTML5 video..   http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Yes, it can do html5 video, but that seems to only work with prerecorded videos stored in mp4 format. I'm look for a live stream, more like a webcam.

Comment: HTML5, does streaming too.  That's what Youtube tends to use nowadays..

Comment: I think our definition of streaming is different. YouTube streams already created content. I'm looking for something to stream a live "cam". Have you heard of MPEG-DASH? It does what I want, but no Windows 7 support.

Comment: maybe our definition of streaming is the same, I am just trying to get across that the video content isn't stored in a file on a web server.

Comment: Yeah, was just looking at the MPEG-DASH,

Comment: Not sure if this will help -> https://bitmovin.com/html5-player/

Comment: It looked promising, until I noticed that their IE support requires Flash or WIndows 8.1+

Comment: Found this -> https://github.com/vbence/stream-m  it appears to use Web-M, as workaround.  Even IE9, supported WebM, so this should do it..  It's also using ffmpeg, that's kind of well supported for connecting your live streams.

Comment: A quick question, does this live stream require sound, and does it require been fast FPS, if not another option is just sending Images,.. A lot of skiing websites used to do this for showing you mountains slopes in real time.

Comment: I do not require audio but I do require a fast FPS, at least 24.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, MPEG-DASH is not available for IE11 under Windows 7 as MSE (Media Source Extensions) is not supported by this config (see [MSE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594470%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

As far as I could read, Flash is the only reliable way to play DASH on IE11+Win7. Yes, this is very sad. It works only for Win 8.1+.

Same problem with HLS, it is only natively supported by Edge on Win10.

Did you manage to find an acceptable compromise? I'm also looking for a solution for the same setup.

Comment: I have not, unfortunately I had to change the client requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution!
After days of searching around, I found [THEOplayer](https://www.theoplayer.com/) which is supposed to work in IE11 under Windows 7 without Flash, without any plugin, as stated on their [HTML5 Support Matrix](https://support.theoplayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208340469-Support-Matrix).

Only downside: it is not free. But pricing seems fair and if you don't aim at millions of video-read per month you should be okay.

Comment: Interesting to note: if the streaming protocol is HLS, THEOplayer can even go back to IE 10.